# Slack Webhooks Connected to Google Sheets Get Next Row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks, slack

I have this code that works great for using an outgoing webhook in slack to fill in a google sheet, and then bounce back a formatted response from the google sheet into a slack channel, but I can't figure out how to get it to pull any other columns in the google sheet. Here is the [google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P4goTvi2a7yjh-fBccRJPJ9ZFNly8OhxmABXkuhfbBQ/edit?usp=sharing). So it goes as follows:

1. In a slack chanel you can use the outgoing webhook and post"nextrow;test;test;test
2. This information is filled into the google sheet with a new row
3. google script formats this info into a payload and posts a formatted version of the info into the slack channel
   This all occurs in columns A:F and in row G there is an array formula and I would like for the google script to pull that columns value in that new row and post it back in the slack response. I tried entering in `sheets.getRangeByName('test').getValue(nR,1)`
   but that didn't work, and I also tried `sheet.getRange(noteTakerCell).getValue()` but that also didn't work and it also seems to keep the whole thing from working anymore. Here is an example of the response posted back in Slack, and I would like this to include the test column new row. [image]
   Here is the code that currently works for columns A:F, I removed script I wrote for trying to get column G new row since it seems to stop everything from working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

   ```
   function doPost(req) {
     var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1P4goTvi2a7yjh-fBccRJPJ9ZFNly8OhxmABXkuhfbBQ');
     var params = req.parameters;

     var nR = getNextRow(sheets) + 1;

     if (params.token == "[Slack Outgoing Webhook]") {

       // PROCESS TEXT FROM MESSAGE
       var textRaw = String(params.text).replace(/^\s*update\s*:*\s*/gi,'');
       var text = textRaw.split(/\s*;\s*/g);

       // FALL BACK TO DEFAULT TEXT IF NO UPDATE PROVIDED
       var project   = text[0] || "No Project Specified";
       var yesterday = text[1] || "No update provided";
       var today     = text[2] || "No update provided";
       var blockers  = text[3] || "No update provided";

       // RECORD TIMESTAMP AND USER NAME IN SPREADSHEET
       sheets.getRangeByName('timestamp').getCell(nR,1).setValue(new Date());
       sheets.getRangeByName('user').getCell(nR,1).setValue(params.user_name);

       // RECORD UPDATE INFORMATION INTO SPREADSHEET
       sheets.getRangeByName('project').getCell(nR,1).setValue(project);
       sheets.getRangeByName('yesterday').getCell(nR,1).setValue(yesterday);
       sheets.getRangeByName('today').getCell(nR,1).setValue(today);
       sheets.getRangeByName('blockers').getCell(nR,1).setValue(blockers);

       var channel = "[Slack Channel]";

       postResponse(channel,params.channel_name,project,params.user_name,yesterday,today,blockers);

     } else {
       return;
     }
   }

   function getNextRow(sheets) {
     var timestamps = sheets.getRangeByName("timestamp").getValues();
     for (i in timestamps) {
       if(timestamps[i][0] == "") {
         return Number(i);
         break;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   ```
   function postResponse(channel, srcChannel, project, userName, yesterday, today, blockers) {

     var payload = {
       "channel": "#" + channel,
       "username": "New Update",
       "icon_emoji": ":white_check_mark:",
       "link_names": 1,
       "attachments":[
          {
             "fallback": "This is an update from a Slackbot integrated into your organization. Your client chose not to show the attachment.",
             "pretext": "*" + project + "* posted an update for stand-up. (Posted by @" + userName + " in #" + srcChannel + ")",
             "mrkdwn_in": ["pretext"],
             "color": "#D00000",
             "fields":[
                {
                   "title":"Yesterday",
                   "value": yesterday,
                   "short":false
                },
                {
                   "title":"Today",
                   "value": today,
                   "short":false
                },
                {
                   "title":"Blockers",
                   "value": blockers,
                   "short": false
              }
             ]
          }
       ]
     };

     var url = '[Slack Incoming Webhook]';
     var options = {
       'method': 'post',
       'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
     };

     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
   }
   ```

Comment: Also, I apologize for the code formatting. I spent like 20mins trying to get it to all be code sample but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: When you tried `sheets.getRangeByName('test').getValue(nR,1)` did you have a corresponding named range (named 'test') already defined?

Comment: @DimuDesigns yes I have the test column name defined as test in the spreadsheet. Thanks!